# The compiler keeps showing the error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'inpu'

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I tried to write a program using array of structure to input and output data. I wanted to input and output values using functions. But I keep getting "incompatible type for argument 1" error. I have mentioned the errors and warnings I get at the end of the code. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student
{   int rno,cls;
    char name[25],sec;
    float p;
};

int a=0;

struct student st[100];

void inpu(struct student st[],int a);
void out(struct student st[],int a);

int main()
{
    inpu(st[100],a);
    out(st[100],a);
    return 0;
}

void inpu(struct student st[],int a)
{   
    int i=0;
    char c;
    do
    {   system("cls");
        printf("\nEnter Roll No.: ");   
        scanf("%d",&st[i].rno);

        printf("\nEnter Name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(st[i].name);

        printf("\nEnter class: ");
        scanf("%d",&st[i].cls);

        printf("\nEnter Section: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        getch(&st[i].sec);

        printf("\nEnter Percentage: ");
        scanf("%f",&st[i].p);

        i++;

        printf("\n\nDo you want to enter more data? (y/n) ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&c);

        if(c=='n')
            break;
    }while(c!='n'||c!='N');
    a=i;
}

void out(struct student st[],int a)
{   int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {   system("cls");
        printf("\nEnter Roll No.: %d",st[i].rno);
        printf("\nEnter Name: %s",st[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter class: %d",st[i].cls);
        printf("\nEnter Section: %s",st[i].sec);
        printf("\nEnter Percentage: %f",st[i].p);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler is showing these errors and warnings:

19  2       [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'inpu'

14  6       [Note] expected 'struct student *' but argument is of type 'struct student'

20  2       [Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'out'

15  6       [Note] expected 'struct student *' but argument is of type 'struct student'

Comment: regarding: `void inpu(struct student st[],int a)` the first parameter is a pointer.  The body of the the function: `inpu()` is failing to treat the first parameter as a pointer.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  This statement is specified in the C standard as undefined behavior.  The function: `fflush()` is only for output streams, not input streams.  Now, some compilers that do not adhere to the C standard, like Visual Studio do allow it but it is not portable.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&c);`   1) fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior, per the C standard.  2) suggest: `scanf( " %c", &c );`  Note the leading ' ' before the `%c` which will consume any leading white space

Comment: in function: `out()`, regarding the two statements: `{   system("cls");`  this will result in the output being erased from the terminal before you get a chance to read it.  Note: the leading `{` should be treated as a separate statement.  therefore, the statement: `system("cls");` should (for ease of readability and understanding) be on the next line

Comment: The following problem occurs many time in the posted code:  regarding: `printf("\nEnter Roll No.: %d",st[i].rno);`  the `st` is a pointer so the statement should be: `printf( "\nEnter Roll No.: %d", st[i]->rno );`  Note the use of `->` to reference the fields in the struct and note the use of horizontal spacing for readability

Comment: regarding: `int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)`  it is best to limit the scope of variables as much as reasonable.  Therefore, suggest: `for( int i=0; i<a; i++ )` which will limit the scope to the body of the `for()` loop

Comment: why have: `if(c=='n')
            break;`  when the following `while()` statement (once corrected) will end the loop

Comment: regarding `a=i;`  The parameter `a` is not a pointer, but rather a passed parameter, so no  change to the global variable `a`.  Note: the use of global variables is a very poor programming practice. Suggest the variable `a` be declared inside `main()` and the address of that variable passed to the sub functions

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%f",&st[i].p);`  should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input conversion specifiers'  In the case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: regarding: `gets(st[i].name);` The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest versions of the c language standard. Suggest using: `fgets()` (which does have a different parameter list so read the MAN page. Always enable the warnings when compiling, so your compiler will tell you about these kinds of problems

Comment: Since both `a` and `st[]` are global variables, there is absolutely no reason to pass them as parameters to the sub functions

Comment: regarding: `getch(&st[i].sec);`  this is not portable,  Suggest: `st[i].sec = getchar()`

Comment: regarding: }while(c!='n'||c!='N'); This will never stop the loop. because the variable c cannot ever satisfy the conditions. Suggest: }while( c!='n' && c!='N' ); Or better, add the statement: #include <ctype.h> and then the statement would be: `}while( c != tolower('n') );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct student st[100];
```

This says `st` is an array of 100 students, from 0 to 99.

```
void inpu(struct student st[],int a);
```

This says that `inpu`'s first parameter must be an array of `student`s.

```
inpu(st[100],a);
```

Oops, `st[100]` is a non-existent entry, past the end of the array. And it's not an array of anything. You probably wanted:

```
inpu(st,a);
```

This passes an array as the first parameter to `inpu`, which is what the prototype said you were going to do.

Comment: Thank you David, it worked. I just realized what a stupid thing I did there.

Comment: @Devanshi then perhaps you should have accepted *this* answer as the best, not the one you did (which gets it right in passing and purely by accident).

Answer (score 0):

try using pointer for your structs, also getch is non standard, this might work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student
{   int rno,cls;
    char name[25],sec;
    float p;
};

int a=0;

struct student st[100];

void inpu(struct student *st,int a);
void out(struct student *st,int a);

int main()
{
    inpu(&st[0],a);
    out(&st[0],a);
    return 0;
}

void inpu(struct student *st,int a)
{
    int i=0;
    char c;
    do
    {   system("cls");
        printf("\nEnter Roll No.: ");
        scanf("%d",&st[i].rno);

        printf("\nEnter Name: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(st[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter class: ");
        scanf("%d",&st[i].cls);

        printf("\nEnter Section: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        st[i].sec =getchar();

        printf("\nEnter Percentage: ");
        scanf(" %f",&st[i].p);

        i++;

        printf("\n\nDo you want to enter more data? (y/n) ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&c);

        if(c=='n')
            break;
    }while(c!='n'||c!='N');
    a=i;
}

void out(struct student *st,int a)
{   int i;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {   system("cls");
        printf("\nEnter Roll No.: %d",st[i].rno);
        printf("\nEnter Name: %s",st[i].name);
        printf("\nEnter class: %d",st[i].cls);
        printf("\nEnter Section: %s",st[i].sec);
        printf("\nEnter Percentage: %f",st[i].p);
    }
}
```